# How do I get an img to fill the viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I achieve a full viewport sized img effect like these sites?
[michaelpumo.com](http://michaelpumo.com/),[www.montere.it](http://www.montere.it/?lang=en)
I want the img to be responsive and fit the entire viewport when someone visits the site. I've tried  using a responsive background img on the html element, which did cover the viewport like I wanted, but any new elements added to the page would just go on top of the img. Instead, I want the user to be able to scroll down and see the rest of the page like on those sites. The same problem occured when I used an inline img.

Comment: Do you have any css or html? There are a lot of variables in your question: if there is text in viewport, if you have sizes defined, etc. Please rephrase with more data

Comment: `vw` and `vh` would do it

Comment: If you are actually setting it as a background image for a particular element such as a `<div>` or on the `<body>`, other elements within those tags will appear on top. Rather, you may have to just use the `<img>` tag and using CSS, style accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a broad question, here is a broad answer. Use `100vh` and `100vw` for the image, see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqjL17b4/).

`img{width: 100vw; height: 100vh;}`

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Make a div and set to him the id `firstview`

```
#firstview { 
  background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Change bg.jpg and put the link to your image .